# Можно ли у SVG элемента или его клона сменить позицию?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg, svg-спрайт

Допустим есть некий холст:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
viewBox="0 0 500 500" width="100%" height="100%"></svg>
```

И есть некий элемент:

```
<path d="M0 0 55 122 0 300 300"/>
```

Положение которого, зависит от координат.

А если этих самых координат вагон и маленькая тележка, не переписывать же их все, чтобы элемент отображался не в верхнем левом углу, а в правом нижнем углу холста.

Есть ли такой элемент ***контейнер*** в SVG в который можно поместить этот элемент `path`, и двигать его куда угодно и как угодно?

```html
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 500 500" width="100%" height="100%"> <path d="M0 0 55 122 0 300 300"/></svg>
```

Comment: есть еще вариант встроить svg инлайн, это даст возможность сделать из него компонент vuejs. соответственно, можно двигать. если интересно могу накидать в виде ответа

Comment: @TotalPusher, любой ответ полезен, не мне, так другому... Пиши если не лень...

Comment: @TotalPusher, а при чём тут vue?

Comment: @Qwertiy, мой ответ ниже

Comment: @TotalPusher, ответ-то видел, а вот как vue относится к вопросу, не понял.

Comment: @Qwertiy, добавляет динамические координаты, чтобы можно было `двигать его куда угодно и как угодно`, как спрашивает ТС. Получается "реактивный" svg.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте для  перемещения одного элемента SVG или группы элементов  команду `transform="translate(x y)"`

Ниже в примере полоса с надписью Start перемещена на `200px` вниз

```html
<style>
    .container {
  width:50%;
  height:50%
        }
  svg {background-color: #d3d3d3;}
   
</style> 
<div class="container">  
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      viewBox="0 0 300 300" >  
      <g id="gr1" text-anchor="middle" >  
   <!-- кнопка -->
 <rect id="rect1" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="30"  fill="#1A2153"/>
  <text id="txt1" x="150" y="22" font-size="28" stroke="white" fill="white"  pointer-events="none" > Start</text>
  </g>  
       <!-- Перемещаем вниз-->
    <g id="gr1" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0 200)" >  
   <!-- кнопка -->
 <rect id="rect1" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="30"  fill="#1A2153"/>
  <text id="txt1" x="150" y="22" font-size="28" stroke="white" fill="white"  pointer-events="none" > Start</text>
  </g>  
  
  </div>
```

**При использовании команды `<use>` тоже есть возможность позиционировать клоны элементов**

```html
  


 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 500 500" width="100%" height="100%">
 <defs>
 <path id="p1" d="M0 0 55 122 0 300 300"/>
</defs>

<use xlink:href="#p1" x="0" y="0" />
<use xlink:href="#p1" x="100" y="0" fill="red" /> 
<use xlink:href="#p1" x="200" y="0" fill="green" />
</svg>
```

Для кроссбраузерности всегда используйте `xlink:href` хотя `Chrome` и некоторые другие браузеры позволяют использовать укороченную команду `href`, но `Safari` такую форму записи не понимает

**Update 19.06.2019**

Добавлен пример после обсуждения в комментариях

- Позиционируем всю группу элементов
- Одновременно закрашиваем, уменьшаем и передвигаем каждый треугольник

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 500 500" width="100%" height="100%">
 <defs>
 <path id="p1" d="M0 0 55 122 0 300 300"/>
</defs>

<!-- Передвигаем вправо всю группу треугольников -->
<g transform="translate(30 0)" >
<!-- Одновременно закрашиваем, уменьшаем и передвигаем каждый треугольник -->
<use xlink:href="#p1" x="0" y="0" />
<use xlink:href="#p1" x="100" y="0" transform="translate(0 30) scale(0.75)" fill="red" /> 
<use xlink:href="#p1" x="200" y="0" transform="translate(30 60) scale(0.5)" fill="green" />
<use xlink:href="#p1" x="200" y="0" transform="translate(120 90) scale(0.25)" fill="purple" />

</g>
```

Comment: Alexandr_TT, привет, про `transform="translate(x y)"` я и сам знал, а ничего другого нет? Думаю еще можно вложить один `svg` в другой, тоже думаю пойдет, но мне казалось есть более изящное решение...Не хотелось бы плодить `transform="translate(x y)"`... Ну если нет, то буду использовать данный метод...

Comment: @Air Можно и svg в svg вкладывать но там сложнее  получится с позиционированием, можно `viewBox` ом двигать, но это опять сложнее. `translate` наиболее универсальное средство, которое позволяет двигать как группу элементов, так и одиночные элементы.

Comment: Alexandr_TT, понятно...  translate так  translate....

Comment: @air со слайдером во втором ответе я не угадал? А то можешь использовать второй ответ с `<obect>`

Comment: Alexandr_TT, у меня столько комментов и ответ был, да еще тут отвлекают, я вторую часть твоего ответа  упустил...  вот в принципе то что надо... Тем более там при переходах страницы у меня меняется цветовая  политра фона, да еще и значки разные.... меняют и расположения и меняются сами...

Comment: Я прекрасно помнил про `defs && use` но не понял как реализовать

Comment: @Air на всякий случай посмотри раздел (метку) [svg-sprite](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg-%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82) разобраны практически все возникающие нюансы

Answer (score 3):

Если вы хотите, как я догадываюсь из примера в вопросе, использовать стрелки SVG многократно на разных HTML страницах, например в слайдерах, то можно использовать метод добавления SVG файлов с помощью `<object>` с последующим многократным использованием с помощью команды `<use>` c позиционированием, как в первом ответе.

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="sprite.svg" width="200" height="200" >
   Your browser does not support SVG
</object>
```

Далее вызываем svg в любом месте HTML:

```
<div class="container">

<svg>
      <use  xlink:href="sprite.svg"#icons--icon1"></use>
</svg>  
</div>
```

И уже контейнер можно позиционировать правилами CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Поместить `path` внутрь другого `svg`, а двигать с помощью `VueJS`. Пример:

```js
"use strict";

new Vue({
  el: "#js-crazy-rectange",
  computed: {
    // вычисляемое свойство - цвет
    fillColorServer: function() {
      return 'green';
    }
  },
  methods: {
    // назначаем новые координаты
    newPos() {
      this.posX = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 150);
      this.posY = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 150);
    }
  },
  // начальные координаты
  data: {
    posX: 0,
    posY: 0
  }
});
```

```css
.m-b-1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="js-crazy-rectange">

  <div>
    <button class="m-b-1" @click="newPos()">Click me</button>
  </div>

  <svg class="pulse-svg" width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

    <svg :x="posX" :y="posY" width="50" height="50">
      <path v-bind:style="{ fill: fillColorServer }" d="M50,0 0,0 0,50 50,50 z"/>
    </svg>

  </svg>

</div>
```

Comment: Ответ хороший, но из серии забивать микроскопом гвозди. ловите плюсик, хотя я приверженец забивать гвозди молотком :-)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT в данном случае гвозди Вуем забиваются ;)